# How to find and replace a value/string with the empty cell in CSV python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, replace

I am working with a CSV file. for example i want to replace all the cell with the value 'C' to black cell. I want my code to find that each cell and make it black.

```
df.replace(to_replace ="C", value = ??)
```

This is my code so far I mainly want to know what is the value = ?? if I want a blank cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.replace(to_replace ="C", value = "")
```

This will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, Use can use the same replace method and then use inplace = True argument to modify the existing dataframe.

```
df.replace({"C": ""}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you explain clearly what you needed, if you want to replace `C` across the whole DataFrame or Just within a `column` that depends, but considering your approach.

**Sample DataFrame:**

```
df
  colA colB
0    A    C
1    B   DC
2    C    E
```

**solutons:**

You can apply **dict-like `to_replace`**

```
df =  df.replace({"C": ""})
print(df)
  colA colB
0    A
1    B   DC
2         E
```

Lets Suppose you want to apply it only for a column `colA`

```
df["colA"] = df["colA"].replace({"C": ""})
print(df)
0    A
1    B
2
```

Note: `dict` is more intuitive over `to_replace` parameter.